# Reload page when only param in URL changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a little problem, but i'm not able to fix it.

I'm on this page :

http://example.com:8080/#/user/5ad142e8063ebb0537c5343e

And i have a link pointing to this URL

http://example.com:8080/#/user/5ac00b02bb055f37b3fd2d07

But when i click on the link. The URL changes, but not the content. The content is not reloaded. If i manually reload the page it works.

The link code is :

```
<router-link  :to="{ name: 'User', params: { id: user.id }}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Profil
</router-link>
```

Is there any way to force the page reloading?

Comment: Can you paste more code? The component at that URL is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html). The component must react to changes in url parameters:

> One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. **However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called.**

There are two ways to handle this, watch the `$route` object:

```
const User = {
     template: '...',
     watch: {
         '$route' (to, from) {
              // react to route changes...
          }
     }
}
```

Or by the `beforeRouteUpdate` guard:

```
const User = {
    template: '...',
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) { 
        // react to route changes... 
        // don't forget to call next() 
    } 
}
```